# Why is the difference between the min and max values ​of jmeter so large?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

[image]

Why is the difference between the minimum and maximum values ​​of jmeter so large?

All tested under the same conditions.

1. laptop reboot
2. tested under different conditions

Answer (score 0):

With just looking at the summary table, we cannot tell the root cause of the problem.

Possible reasons could be

- There seems spike in response times which you can check in Response Time graph.
- Spikes may occur for multiple reasons (Low on CPU/Memory, Network Issue etc.)

Watch for the pattern of spikes and correlate the Time of Spike occurrence with server side statistics to find more on root cause.